# Using SQL Server and getting syntax error at SET @sql command

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EasyMetrics]
AS
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000)

    --drop existing temp tables
    IF object_id('tempdb..#mkg_metrics') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE #mkg_metrics

    --create temp working tables
    CREATE TABLE #mkg_metrics 
    (
         TR_EM_NO CHAR(11),
         TR_DATE_TIME DATETIME,
         TRAN_TYPE CHAR(4),
         QUANTITY NUMERIC(10,0),
         TR_STAGE_LOCATION CHAR(15),
         TR_loca CHAR(10),
         DOCK CHAR(2),
         VD_NAME VARCHAR(36)


    --Pull fields out of large tables into temp table for faster query
    SET @sql = "INSERT INTO #mkg_metrics
                    SELECT TR_EM_NO, TR_DATE_TIME, TRAN_TYPE, QUANTITY, TR_STAGE_LOCATION, TR_loca
                    FROM LOGTRAN 
                    INNER JOIN TRAILER_LOG tl
                    WHERE TR_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, getdate()) 
                      AND TR_DATE_TIME <= GETDATE() 
                      AND tl.TRAN_TYPE = 'SETUP'

    INSERT INTO #mkg_metrics
        SELECT
            tl.DOCK
        FROM
            LOGTRAN 
        INNER JOIN
            TRAILER_LOG tl
        WHERE
            TR_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) 
            AND TR_DATE_TIME <= GETDATE() 
            AND tl.TRAN_TYPE = 'SETUP'

    INSERT INTO #mkg_metrics
        SELECT 
            vm.VD_NAME
        FROM
            LOGTRAN 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            IMMAS im ON im.VD_NO = vm.VD_NO 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            TRAILER_LOG tl
        WHERE
            TR_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) 
            AND TR_DATE_TIME <= GETDATE() 
            AND tl.TRAN_TYPE = 'SETUP'

    --print @sql
    exec(@sql)

    SELECT DISTICNT
        TR_EM_NO, TR_DATE_TIME, TRAN_TYPE, QUANTITY, TR_STAGE_LOCATION, 
        TR_loca, DOCK, VD_NAME
    FROM
        mkg_metrics 
    ORDER BY
        TR_DATE_TIME
```

Comment: SQL Server uses single quotes (`'`) for literal strings, not double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Will help if you show the error message.

Comment: Why are you using Dynamic SQL anyway? There's nothing dynamic about it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no closing parenthesis at the end of `create table #mkg_metrics` statement.

```
create table #mkg_metrics (TR_EM_NO char(11),TR_DATE_TIME datetime,TRAN_TYPE char(4),QUANTITY numeric(10,0),TR_STAGE_LOCATION char(15),TR_loca char(10),DOCK char(2),
VD_NAME varchar(36))
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that haha Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/DYQ62776)**

Use single quotes for string literals, and escape single quotes twice

```
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = '
insert into #mkg_metrics
    select TR_EM_NO, TR_DATE_TIME, TRAN_TYPE, QUANTITY, TR_STAGE_LOCATION, TR_loca
    from LOGTRAN inner join TRAILER_LOG tl
    where TR_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, getdate()) and TR_DATE_TIME <= GETDATE() and tl.TRAN_TYPE = ''SETUP''

insert into #mkg_metrics
    select tl.DOCK
    from LOGTRAN inner join TRAILER_LOG tl
    where TR_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, getdate()) and TR_DATE_TIME <= GETDATE() and tl.TRAN_TYPE = ''SETUP''

insert into #mkg_metrics
    select vm.VD_NAME
    from LOGTRAN left outer join IMMAS im
    on im.VD_NO = vm.VD_NO left outer join TRAILER_LOG tl
    where TR_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, getdate()) and TR_DATE_TIME <= GETDATE() and tl.TRAN_TYPE = ''SETUP''
';

SELECT @sql;
```